# Chrome search input width not same as text input

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Firefox text and search input types both appear to be the same width.

In Chrome they are different widths.

Funnily enough my Codepen http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/eBpyzK has the opposite result to my actual code (search appears wider).

```css
input {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: padding-box !important;
}

form {width: 500px;}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
 <input type="text" placeholder="Text" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: `padding-box`? shouldn't it be `border-box`?

Comment: added explanation why this is happening to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You shouldn't use the `padding-box` anymore:**

> The width and height properties include the content, the padding but neither the border, nor the margin. Only Firefox implemented this value, and it was removed in Firefox 50.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

**But why is this happening?**

So you are using the not supported `padding-box`, Google Chrome is using the default values for `box-sizing`. The default value for the `<input type="search">` is `border-box`. The default value of the `<input type="text"/>` is `content-box`.

**See this example (should look like your example):**

```css
input {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 1rem;
}
input[type="search"] {
  box-sizing:border-box; /** default for this input */
}
input[type="text"] {
  box-sizing:content-box; /** default for this input */  
}
form {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Text" />
</form>
```

**You can use `border-box` instead:**

```css
input {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Text" />
</form>
```

**Difference between `padding-box` and `border-box`?**

On `border-box` the width and height of the element includes the content, padding and border but not the margin of the element. On `padding-box` the width and height includes the content and padding but not the border and margin.

So if you want to simulate the `padding-box` you have to include the width of the border to the padding and using the `border-box`.

**Your example would look like this:**

```css
input {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: calc(1rem + 2px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Text" />
</form>
```

**Hint:** The default width of the `<input>` border is 2px.

Comment: Thanks. I've been seeing and using it all over the place and didn't realise it no longer worked.